# Load runner Java applet recording

Tags: java, applet, loadrunner

I'm recording finacle 10.x application using vu 12.02.. When I click on Login button I am getting error:

> could not perform login.. applet not loaded properly.

Same error I am getting without installing Java when I was trying to login with browser only, but now I have install JRE 1.7 and I am able to login with browser. But still I am getting error when I start recording.

Answer (score 0):

Check out whether you are using 32 bit Java or 64 bit java.  It makes a difference when your VUGEN is a 32 bit component and is running in the Windows on Windows 32 Subsystem and your Java is running in the 64 bit subsystem